# php sort array of version strings

Tags: php

I would like to sort an array of version strings in php.

Input would be something like this:

```
["2019.1.1.0", "2019.2.3.0", "2019.2.11.0", "2020.1.0.0", "2019.1.3.0", "2019.3.0.0"]
```

What is the easiest way to sort this? Sorting the strings as is does not work, because that would put the "2019.2.11.0" before "2019.2.3.0" and that is of course not what I want.

Result should be

```
["2019.1.1.0", "2019.1.3.0", "2019.2.3.0", "2019.2.11.0", "2019.3.0.0", "2020.1.0.0"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are searching for a natural sort.

```php
$versions = ["2019.1.1.0", "2019.2.3.0", "2019.2.11.0", "2020.1.0.0", "2019.1.3.0", "2019.3.0.0"];
$sorted = $versions;
natsort($sorted);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019.1.1.0
    [4] => 2019.1.3.0
    [1] => 2019.2.3.0
    [2] => 2019.2.11.0
    [5] => 2019.3.0.0
    [3] => 2020.1.0.0
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `version_compare` function.

This is how to use `usort` with version_compare.

```php
$a = ["2019.1.1.0", "2019.2.3.0", "2019.2.11.0", "2020.1.0.0", "2019.1.3.0", "2019.3.0.0"];

usort($a, 'version_compare');

var_dump($a);
```

Result

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2019.1.1.0"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2019.1.3.0"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2019.2.3.0"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "2019.2.11.0"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "2019.3.0.0"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "2020.1.0.0"
}
```